# Why json only display id for already serialized objects in the result data serialization?

Tags: java, json

I'm curios about this rest return with id in place of a object serialization.

I start to take notice when working with rest and complex classes their response body contains ids in place of a object as follow in  "supplier" with id 2, "item" with id 3 and in "warehouse" with id 5:

```
{
   "code": 1,
   "message": "Entities returned Successfully !",
   "t":    [
            {
         "@id": 1,
         "id": 2,
         "date": "01/02/2016",
         "supplier":          {
            "@id": 2,
            "id": 2,
            "code": "codfor",
            "name": "namfor"
         },
         "item":          {
            "@id": 3,
            "id": 2,
            "code": "code",
            "descricao": "descricao",
            "unity":             {
               "@id": 4,
               "id": 2,
               "unity": "nomeb"
            },
            "total": 11.33,
            "warehouse":             {
               "@id": 5,
               "id": 2,
               "local": "localb",
               "row": "corredorb",
               "shelf": "prateleirab",
               "floor": "andarb",
               "box": "boxb",
               "unity": 4,
               "total": 22.66,
               "items":                [
                  3,
                  3
               ]
            }
         },
         "warehouse": 5,
         "note": 22222,
         "size": 1.44,
         "price": 33.44
      },
            {
         "@id": 6,
         "id": 3,
         "date": "01/02/2016",
         "supplier": 2,
         "item": 3,
         "warehouse": 5,
         "note": 22222,
         "size": 1.44,
         "price": 33.44
      }
   ]
}
```

So this is a feature or a bug in my project?
Where is the property or a fix to set a full serialization in spring or even in json?

Comment: Do you have `@JsonIdentityInfo` or  `@JsonValue` on your POJO?

Comment: Yes, I have one and is set this way: @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")

Comment: that's why variable names are getting replaced by @id